# How to thread an entire function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

My goal is to re-write an old codebase to have a function that downloads urls do so concurrently, and I would like to avoid writing `threading.Thread(target = func_that_downloads_things).start()` everywhere that function is currently coded into the program.

If I could just keep most of the old codebase which reads `func_that_downloads_things()` instead (and work the threading functionality directly into the one function that does the downloading), that would be amazing.

This code downloads all 4 urls concurrently:

```
import requests, threading, time

def func_that_downloads_things():
    request_method = 'GET'
    request_url = 'http://olympus.realpython.org/dice'
    r = requests.request(method=request_method, url=request_url, timeout=4)
    print(r.text + '... took ' + str(round(time.time() - thread_start_time, 4)) + " seconds to download... and threading.active_count() is at " + str(threading.active_count()))

#take the start time
thread_start_time = time.time()

#download 4 websites
threading.Thread(target = func_that_downloads_things).start()
threading.Thread(target = func_that_downloads_things).start()
threading.Thread(target = func_that_downloads_things).start()
threading.Thread(target = func_that_downloads_things).start()

#take the end time
thread_end_time = time.time()

#tell the world how long it took to start the threads and get to this point
print('took '+ str(round(thread_end_time - thread_start_time, 6)) + ' seconds to initiate all the downloads')

print("threading.active_count() is at " + str(threading.active_count()))
```

While this code does not:

```
import requests, threading, time

def func_that_downloads_things(url):
    def dl(url):
        request_method = 'GET'
        request_url = url
        r = requests.request(method=request_method, url=request_url, timeout=4)
        print(r.text + '... took ' + str(round(time.time() - thread_start_time, 4)) + " seconds to download... and threading.active_count() is at " + str(threading.active_count()))
    threading.Thread(target = dl(url)).start()

#take the start time
thread_start_time = time.time()

#download 4 websites
func_that_downloads_things('http://olympus.realpython.org/dice')
func_that_downloads_things('http://olympus.realpython.org/dice')
func_that_downloads_things('http://olympus.realpython.org/dice')
func_that_downloads_things('http://olympus.realpython.org/dice')

#take the end time
thread_end_time = time.time()

#tell the world how long it took to start the threads and get to this point
print('took '+ str(round(thread_end_time - thread_start_time, 6)) + ' seconds to initiate all the downloads')

print("threading.active_count() is at " + str(threading.active_count()))
```

Why?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `ThreadPoolExecutor` example from the docs for a rather 'sleek'/universal interface: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: Because the main thread is not spinning the new thread. After call to the function main thread will wait till the function execution is completed. Inside the function is where you have initialized the thread. So technically there is only one thread that is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`threading.Thread(target = dl(url)).start()`

by

`threading.Thread(target = dl, args=(url,)).start()`

Your code first runs `dl(url)` before the thread is even created because writing it that way is always a call to a function (or constructor).

The second code only hands the uncalled function object to the thread object along with the argument. The function is then called later with the given argument in the newly created thread.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you. I will mark your question as correct in 6 minutes (as I am not allowed to yet, that was fast!), but in the meanwhile... can you elaborate as to why exactly adding the args separately made threading do what I expected it to do?

Comment: @randy I have added some explanation to my answer.